# How to add TextField to Cell using tags in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, swift2

I want the first row of a table to have a cell with a TextField (in my case named FindTextField).
The way I have implemented (see code below), as the cells are reused and if the list of cells is scrolled down, then more cells will be assigned with the TextField. I would like to know how can I use tags or anything else that allows to force that only the first row will have the TextField even if the user scrolls all the way down and then up.

Now, here is the code:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("identifier",
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            FindTextField.frame = CGRectMake(74, 4, cell.bounds.width - 78 , cell.bounds.height - 8)
            FindTextField.hidden = false
            FindTextField.placeholder = "Find"
            FindTextField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
            FindTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
            FindTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
            FindTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
            FindTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
            FindTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;
            FindTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
            FindTextField.delegate = self
            FindTextField.autocapitalizationType = .AllCharacters
            cell.contentView.addSubview(FindTextField)
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "menu_find.png")
            cell.textLabel?.hidden = true
        }

        cell.textLabel!.text = StationsChatList[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(24)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor

        return cell

}
```

Comment: Why use tags?  Create two custom cells, one with a `UITextField` and one without.  Dequeue the cell with the text field for indexPath 0 and the cell without the text field for all other indexPaths.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `tag` to your `textField`, and later access it. And when `row != 0` simply hide it. This is what I'm talking about:

```
if cell.viewWithTag(1001) == nil { // init your text field
  FindTextField.frame = ...
  FindTextField.tag = 1001 // or whatever you want
  ...
}
cell.viewWithTag(1001)?.hidden = indexPath.row != 0
...
```

There is another way - implement `prepareForReuse()` method inside your cell and manually hide `FindTextField` (it will be hidden for each cell). And later inside `cellForRow` make it visible if `row == 0`.